# Convert Integer or Float to Year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer

I am trying to convert a column with type Integer to Year. Here is my situation:

```
Original Column: June 13, 1980 (United States)
```

I split and slice it into

```
Year Column: 1980
```

Here, I tried to use:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'])
```

It changed the column to have the year is different from the Original column. For example,

```
Original     Year
1980         1970
2000         1970
2016         1970
```

I am looking forward to your help. Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Tu Le

Comment: you also need to specify the format in that case

Comment: Don't split the text to get the date value. use `to_datetime` and pass a correct `format`. Then you can get any value related to datetime. such as year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Year'] = df['Original'].astype(str).astype('datetime64')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Original       Year
0     1980 1980-01-01
1     2000 2000-01-01
2     2016 2016-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

If need datetimes from year, it means also added `month=1` and `day=1` add `format` parameter, here `%Y` for `YYYY`:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y') 
print (df)
   Original       Year
0      1980 1970-01-01
1      2000 1970-01-01
2      2016 1970-01-01
```

Comment: Thank you Very much. I figured it out. :)

Comment: @tule - working well?